# Using custom activation function with TF-Lite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am new to TensorFlow Lite and ran into a problem using a custom activation function (f(x) = x^2).

Making the model quantization aware, compiling, training and evaluating works fine. However, trying to convert the model has turned into a problem. I tried following the "Quantization aware training comprehensive guide" and created a custom QuantizeConfig. As the quantization of weights is the part that I am mainly interested in, I used the same technique as in the "Modify parts of layer to quantize" section, and skip quantizing the activations:

```
def get_activations_and_quantizers(self, layer):
    # Skip quantizing activations.
    return []

def set_quantize_activations(self, layer, quantize_activations):
    # Empty since `get_activaations_and_quantizers` returns
    # an empty list.
    return
```

However, when trying to convert the model, I get the following errors/ exceptions:

```
File "C:\[..]\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\wrap_toco.py", line 32, in wrapped_toco_convert
  return _pywrap_toco_api.TocoConvert(
Exception: C:\[...]\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py:5793:1: error: 'std.constant' op requires attribute's type ('tensor<20x20xf32>') to match op's return type ('tensor<*xf32>')
_, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
```

and

```
File "C:\[...]\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py", line 183, in toco_convert_protos
  raise ConverterError(str(e))
tensorflow.lite.python.convert.ConverterError: C:\[...]\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py:5793:1: error: 'std.constant' op requires attribute's type ('tensor<20x20xf32>') to match op's return type ('tensor<*xf32>')
_, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
```

Is it possible to only quantize the weights and not the activation function? If not, are there any examples out there describing how to quantize custom activation functions? I haven't found anything among those lines while googling and got lost trying to search for it in the source code.

For reference, this is what I am using to convert the model:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(quant_aware_model)
converter.allow_custom_ops = True
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
    tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,
    tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS
]
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
quantized_tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(quantized_tflite_model)
```

**Edit (what else I tried):**

- Trying to implement a custom layer that does the squaring in the `call` method. Had the same problems as with the custom activation function.
- Using the `tf.keras.layers.Multiply()` layer instead of an activation function, right after the relevant layers. But layer is not supported and needs to be passed with a `QuantizeConfig` into `quantize_annotate_layer()`. However, doing this lead to the exact same problem as above: only converting the model doesn't work, same error as above as well.
- Using `tf.math.multiply(x, x)`. On its own it didn't work because `Layer tf_op_layer_Mul:<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer.TensorFlowOpLayer'> is not supported`. The error message stated that, again, a `QuantizeConfig` and the `quantize_annotate_layer()` function should be used. I tried that but couldn't make it work at all.
- Finally, I tried to make squared versions of the layers (Dense and Conv2D) that would need the squared activation function. I did this by inhereting the respective layer, overwriting the parent's `call` function by first using `super` to get the original result and then returning the squared output. I used the `Default8BitQuantizeConfig` and `Default8BitConvQuantizeConfig` to annotate the layers, respectively. This worked with the Dense layer, but not with Conv2D. Again, the Conv2D version produced the same error as described above when trying to convert the model.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a multiply layer for this rather than a custom function?

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans I tried using a custom layer that performs the squaring in the call method but that gave me the exact same error

Comment: I meant use TF's multiply operation: `tf.math.multiply(x, x)`. According to the docs, TFLite can also do this. No need for custom anything.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans I tried that (and a couple of other things, see the edit) today, but unfortunately I couldn't get it to work.